# Intellij - Unable to download zip from nexus repository, but can download the same from browser

Tags: intellij-idea, nexus

My spring project in intellij is trying to download a plugin from internal nexus repository. 
It fails with a 403 error.

However, the same url can be accessed from the chrome browser and download succeeds.

What am i missing in intellij ??

FYI , intellij is intalled on a mount directory on a cloud profile( "using remote connection since the lockdown"). Chrome is on the C: drive on the same cloud profile(obviously).

I thought this could be a certificate issue , but the when i try to get the certificate from " Developer tools- > Security, then it says the site is not secure.

I am using gradle for the build.

Thanks

Comment: Can you build by Maven from command line? If your nexus repository uses authentication or you use proxy in the network you must configure in in Maven settings.

Comment: Edit - i am using gradle for build. I could solve the issue where gradle zip was not being found, by specifying gradle path in settings -> build tools -> gradle -> use gradle from specified location